# c++ doubly linked list error C2664 'object1::object1(object1 &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const object1 &'

Tags: c++

As i mentioned before am trying to implement in c++ doubly linked list and i have an problem with add at Head function that pops this error whenever i try to add anything to this (tho there might be another errors in this program but for now i wanted to test at least adding an element), am c++ rookie kind of so yeah i dont have much idea how can i solve it

Code:

```
struct object1
{
    int data1;
    char data2;
};

struct object2
{
    double data3;
    bool data4;
};

template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T data = NULL;
    Node<T>* prev = NULL;
    Node<T>* next = NULL;`

}; 

template <class T>
class list

{
Node<T>* head;
Node<T>* tail;
int size = 0;


public:

list() {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}
    void addAtTail(T data)
    {
        Node<T> temp = new Node<T>();
        temp->data = data;
        if (this->size == 0)
        {
            this->head = temp;
            this->tail = temp;


        }
        else if (size > 0)
        {
            this->tail->next = temp;
            temp->prev = this->tail;
            this->tail = temp;

        }
        size++;

    }
    void addAtHead(T data)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>();
        temp->data = data;
        if (this->size == 0)
        {
            this->head = temp;
            this->tail = temp;
        }
        else if (size > 0)
        {
            this->head->prev = temp;
            temp->next = this->head;
            this->head = temp;
        }
        size++;
    }

    void deleteLast()
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            //std::cout << "list is empty you cannot delete anything";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T>* temp = this->tail->prev;
            delete this->tail;
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                this->tail = temp;
                temp->next = NULL;

            }
            else {
                this->head = NULL;
                this->tail = NULL;
            }
            size--;
        }
    }

    void deleteFirst()
    {
        if (size == 0)
            return;
        else {
            Node<T>*temp = this->head->next;
            delete this->head;
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                this->head = temp;
                this->prev = NULL;

            }
            this->head = NULL;
            this->tail = NULL;
            size--;
        }

    }
    void toString() {
        if (this->size == 0)
            std::cout << "lista ma 0 elementow";
        else if (this->size < 6)
            std::cout << "lista posiada" << this->size << "elementow";
        else if (this->size >= 6)
            std::cout << "1." << this->head << "2." << this->head->prev << "\n.\n.\n.\n" << this->tail->next << "\n" << this->tail;
    }
};








int main()
{
    object1 so;
    so.data1 = 1;
    so.data2 = 'c';
    list<object1>* lista = new list<object1>();

lista->addAtHead(so);

int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
int s = 3;
//std::cout << "1." << a << "\n 2." << b << "\n.\n.\n.\n" << c << s;
//std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; `
}
```

appreciate any help.

Comment: `T data = NULL;` this is incorrect. You have an arbitrary type T to which youre trying to assign 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting your code into <kbd>[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8b1f2dff6fb02d1)</kbd> (after removing the stray ` character and adding `#include`s) yields a more informative message:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr Node<object1>::Node()':
main.cpp:63:25:   required from 'void list<T>::addAtHead(T) [with T = object1]'
main.cpp:147:20:   required from here
main.cpp:20:7: error: could not convert '0' from 'long int' to 'object1'
   20 |     T data = NULL;
      |       ^~~~
      |       |
      |       long int
```

This is pointing out that line 20 `T data = NULL;` does not work when `T` is type `object1` because it is not a pointer.

You have two options to fix it: use a constructor or use constructor-less initialization in the body of the class, as you have here.

**Option 1: Use a pointer**

If you change the declaration to `T* data = NULL;`, this will make `data` a pointer rather than a value. You'll need to modify any usage of `data` throughout to be through this pointer instead of as a value. The compiler will tell you about virtually all of these spots to fix. But really you should probably use `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead if you want to go this way since it clearly defines who owns this data.

**Option 2: Default Initialize a Value**

Make that declaration `T data{};` to default initialize as a value rather than a pointer. Here it is building on <kbd>[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caef0ba4e849cd01)</kbd>.

**Option 3: Use a constructor**

As noted in the comments, you could add a constructor to the `Node` class to to pass in the value for `data`:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T data;
    Node<T>* prev = NULL;
    Node<T>* next = NULL;`

    explicit Data( T t ) : data{ std::move(t) } {}
};
```

This uses the `std::move()` function to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Or, dont have a default constructor on node and assign it from the ctor parameter